ASP.NET CORE WEB API webRootPath issue
I have created the new asp.net core web API project using dotnet8.
I wanted to use wwwroot as my web root path.
I added this line to my program.cs:
app.UseStaticFiles();

And I have tried to get that wwwroot path in my Service.cs, and I got null instead of the path:
webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath

I also tried to add this line to my program.cs but the result is the same:
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets().UseWebRoot("wwwroot");

I am know I can got that path like that but I want to use the right way and don't use that customization.
There is my service:

namespace Infrastructure.Services;

public class LocalFileService(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, ILogger<LocalFileService> logger) : IFileService
{
    public async Task<string> SaveFromBase64(string content, FilePlaces place = FilePlaces.Web,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        string path, result, filename = GetFileExtension(content);
        switch (place)
        {
            default:
                result = $"/products/{Guid.NewGuid():N}.{filename}";
                path = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot", result);
                logger.LogInformation("saving file {path}", path);
                break;
        }

        await using var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
        await fileStream.WriteAsync(bytes, cancellationToken);
        return result;
    }

    private static string GetFileExtension(string base64String)
    {
        var data = base64String.Substring(0, 5);

        switch (data.ToUpper())
        {
            case "IVBOR":
                return "png";
            case "/9J/4":
                return "jpg";
            case "AAAAF":
                return "mp4";
            case "JVBER":
                return "pdf";
            case "AAABA":
                return "ico";
            case "UMFYI":
                return "rar";
            case "E1XYD":
                return "rtf";
            case "U1PKC":
                return "txt";
            case "MQOWM":
            case "77U/M":
                return "srt";
            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

And there is my Program.cs:
using Application;
using Infrastructure;
using Infrastructure.Persistence;
using Infrastructure.Persistence.Contexts;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApi;

string basedir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

WebApplicationOptions options = new()
{
    ContentRootPath = basedir,
    Args= args,
    WebRootPath = Path.Combine(basedir, "wwwroot")
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);

builder.Services.AddApplication();
builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddWebApi();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(s => s.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().Build());

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var dbContextInitializer = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContextInitializer>();

    var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    if (dbContext.Database.IsRelational())
    {
        await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
    }

    await dbContextInitializer.SeedAsync();
}

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

public abstract partial class Program;


My Service.cs is in infrastructure (that is in another project)

First, the root is ContentRootPath. Second, it seems that what you really need to do is map an additional folder, not create an additional service. How is LocalFileService used anyway? Where does it get IWebHostEnvironment from?

Try this.
string basedir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

WebApplicationOptions options = new()
{
  ContentRootPath = basedir,
  Args= args,
  WebRootPath = Path.Combine(basedir, "wwwroot")
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);


Thank you for your answer. I have tried that. But it doesn't work. I have added the service to my question. Can you review again pls

Hi @Firuz builder.Services.AddTransient<IFileService, LocalFileService>(); Try to add this line in your Program.cs file.

Hi @Jason. I did that in my extension method

No I am getting path with custom Path.combine(env.get)...
